# Not able to change range slider thumb (icon) in android

Tags: android, xml, rangeslider

Here is the code I used

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
    android:id="@+id/rangeSlider"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:thumb="@drawable/ic_dots_select"
    android:valueFrom="1"
    android:valueTo="100"
    app:labelBehavior="gone"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Slider"
    app:values="@array/initial_range_slider_values"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvYear" />
```

I already added a thumb icon but it is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

You can change thumb color but it's not possible to change thumb icon for this view. Because `thumb` xml attribute is not supported for `RangeSlider`.
You can find the list of all possible attributes for this view at the official site:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/slider/RangeSlider#xml-attributes_1

You can also investigate the code of `RangeSlider` and `BaseSlider` both don't support thumb attribute.